# Euler's theorem concept

Tags: number-theory

I have understood the proof of Euler's Theorem that comes in number theory.
After completing the proof we conclude that $ar_1,ar_2,...,ar_{\phi(n)}$ are distinct and $\phi(n)$ in number so they are congruent to $r_1,r_2,...,r_{\phi(n)}$. My doubt is how can we simply understand it. That is, why $ar_i$ is not congruent to some other value less than $m$ and which is not relatively prime to $m$? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $ar_i\equiv b\pmod m$ and $\gcd(b,m)>1$, then $\gcd(ar_i,m)>1$.

But since $\gcd(a,m)=1$ and $\gcd(r_i,m)=1$, that's impossible.